# <a> tag URL not working in iPad & iPhone

Tags: html, ipad, salesforce

Iam using below code in sales force platform but its not working in iPad & iPhone. its working in all browsers in Desktop & Android mobile.

```
<a target="_blank" href="/idp/login?app=0sp110000004CJX">
Learning Channel
<span class="doublearrow">
<i class="fa fa-angle-double-right">
</i></span></a>
```

please help.

Comment: Compulsory to use _blank?

Comment: Yes. _blank required.

Comment: Try with others target like _self, _parent, _top. if it works, means only that property have issue